# Increment ems/rems by 0.1 in firebug or chrome dev tools?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools, firebug, font-size

Trying out the EM Koolade but getting frustrated while working in firebug or chrome dev tools as the size jumps are too big.

Is there a way to configure these tools to increment rems or ems by 0.1 instead of 1 on the fly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hold ALT and press the up arrow. You can also hold ALT and scroll up with a mouse or its equivalent with a touchpad (Just make sure your cursor is on the size).

Comment: I can confirm that on Firefox Mac its command+arrow-up. Mac Chrome ALT+arrow-up. On PC Firefox CTRL+arrow-up. PC Chrome both ALT and CTRL+arrow-up